# Add not applicable to all empty input fields on submit

Tags: jquery

I’d be very grateful with any help. I’m trying to add `‘not applicable’` to any empty input fields that are not relevant within section/s of a form on submit. Sections of the form get disabled/hidden depending on selection/s hence why I would like to achieve the below effect

My target is...

```
question: “Not Applicable” 
question 2:” Not Applicable” and so forth but not 

“question:           “  in the recipients email
```

I'm using the latest jQuery library and the validation plugin.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd love to show you but I have used some many variations of code - plus I have deleted anything that didn't work, sorry Nick

Comment: u can add u r code in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Thanks - http://jsfiddle.net/KvJjW/

Comment: Hey ThulasiRam - have you had a chance to look at code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this way:-

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $("input[class='required']").each(function(){
          if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0)               
              $(this).val('Not Applicable');
    });
});
```

Once validation is OK then go for submitting the form.

Comment: Thanks Siva that worked great! However, how do I get the validation to work first to all active inputs? At the moment it’s validating because Not Applicable is being entered. Pseudo code would be if  input ‘.required/element’ is disabled/hidden and equal to “null” then add ‘Not Applicable’ else do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have worked it out - can you confirm if this logic is correct?

```
$("#submit").click(function(){

 $("input[class='required']").each(function(){

      if ($.trim($(this).val().length == 0) && $(this).attr('disabled'))

         $(this).val('Not Applicable');    

      });

 });
```

Comment: I'm hoping this will give me the attended outcome - http://jsfiddle.net/gB3dx/35/